# Given two events, find which of the two is more likely to happen.

Tags: probability

A three-man jury has two members each of whom independently has probability p of making the correct decision and a third member who ﬂips a fair coin for each decision (majority rules). There is also a one-man jury that has a probability p of making the correct decision. Which jury is more likely to make the correct decision?

This is what I've tried for the three-man jury; P(2 men get it correct) + P(3 men correct):

$$P(correct) = p \cdot p \cdot 0.5 + p \cdot (1-p) \cdot 0.5 + (1-p)\cdot p \cdot 0.5 + p \cdot p \cdot 0.5 = p$$

Since I know that for the one-man jury:

$$P(correct) = p$$

Then, that means that they are both equally likely to be correct. Is that right?

Comment: yes, nice coincidence!  but if you draw a $2\times 2$ square for the first two jurors' decisions you can see how this happened "geometrically"

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to double check since on Chegg someone gave an answer in which they set the first equation equal to $p - p^2$ with no explanation as to how they got that result.

Comment: You're welcome.  BTW, $P(correct) = p - p^2$ is clearly wrong, because if $p=1$ then $p- p^2 = 0$...